# python regex multiple find

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to extract properly some cookies from a web request.
Basically i have this string:

```
 str="""Cole_gal_langid=0; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_styleid=4; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_viewid=test; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_appid=gal; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_navk=common.invalidBookmark; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_trans=InvalidBookmark; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT"""
```

I want to remove all "Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT," entries within this string.
so this string become this:

```
str="""Cole_gal_langid=0; Cole_gal_styleid=4; Cole_gal_viewid=test; Cole_gal_appid=gal; Cole_gal_navk=common.invalidBookmark; Cole_gal_trans=InvalidBookmark;"""
```

I was thinking of using Re for this :

```
import re

str="""Cole_gal_langid=0; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_styleid=4; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_viewid=test; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_appid=gal; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_navk=common.invalidBookmark; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT, Cole_gal_trans=InvalidBookmark; Expires=Sun, 14-Jul-13 20:37:22 GMT"""

a = re.search('(Cole_gal_*.\=*)[^;]*', str)
if a:
   quote = "Regex found this: "+a.group(0)+"\r\n"
   print quote
```

Unfortunatly, i only get one result instead of all of the actual cookies

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Nice post.  I like that you showed example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removes multiple occurrences of a pattern a job for [*re.sub*](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> re.sub(r'Expires=.*?GMT([,;]|$)', '', s)
'Cole_gal_langid=0;  Cole_gal_styleid=4;  Cole_gal_viewid=test;  Cole_gal_appid=gal;  Cole_gal_navk=common.invalidBookmark;  Cole_gal_trans=InvalidBookmark; '
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall)?

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `re.finditer` function.